# json issue in HIVE

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

create table src (myjson string);

```
insert into src values {"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"2.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"7.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}} US 123

{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}} CAV 12673


{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}} XR 123sd2
```

i want data like shown below while doing select 
Any hint, how can acheive this ?

```
ver os  XYZ         founder         country     number
1   ms  123.dfer     3.0            us          123
1   ms  123.dfer     2.0            us          123
1   ms  123.dfer     7.0.0          us          123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_json_object(col, '$.Rtype.ver'), get_json_object(col, '$.Rtype.os')` with select clause from table src

[image]

Comment: how do i get founder values for each ver?

Comment: select get_json_object(j22.line, '$.Rtype.MOD.Version.founder') from src See the output attached in Answer section. You can also use "LATERAL VIEW explode" to arrange.

Comment: JUST AN INFORMATION : Your json is not parse well, gives syntax error . I use http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @BigD please make the answer as correct if it works for you.