# Date conversion issue in hive due to UTC time

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have time like `2017-05-04T23:25:23.234Z`  i want to get  `2017-05-04 23:25:23.234` using HIVE. How can achieve this ?

actual data - `2017-05-04T23:25:23.234Z`   expected - `2017-05-04 23:25:23.234`
actual data - `2016-05-04T02:29:23.231234Z`   expected - `2016-05-04 02:29:23.231234`

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select translate('2017-05-04T23:25:23.234Z','TZ',' ')
```

> 2017-05-04 23:25:23.234

Comment: Thanks @Dudu for you help.

Comment: can you also help on below question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511851/json-issue-in-hive/43514473#43514473